# I just can't get my expected output. It's going over my head. What's wrong?

Tags: c

I was just trying to write a linear search program in C. But I'm not getting expected output for some reason that I don't understand. Please, someone, explain what I've done wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int arr[5];
    int query;
    bool found = false;
    int index;

    printf("Insert five elements of your choice: \n");
    /*
        Getting 5 input from user.
    */
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Element %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("What number you are looking for: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &query);

    /*
        Checking if the the number is in the array or not!
    */
    for(int check=0; check<5; check++){
        if(arr[check] == query){
            found = true;
            index = check;
        }
    }

    if(found){
        printf("Result: %d was found in index %d.\n", query, index);
    }else
    {
        printf("Result: Item was not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What is the actual output? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: By the way, it won't help you using the `#` for the question text. You won't get any attention with this and some peaple who could answer your question that see this may look for other questions immediately.

Comment: When I was getting user input to fill the array, it hangs after the first input. And even if the number is in the array it fails to check. I don't know why.

Comment: I'm new here. I don't understand much about the formalities. So, I am sorry for any kind of mistake and please guide me through if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function is able to read variables (using conversion specifiers like `%d`), exact symbols and any number of whitespace characters. If you specify `\n` in your format string, the `scanf` function will try to process **any** number of newlines you've hit. You may fix it by removing `\n` from format string at `scanf` call.